# Do processes have their own memory?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

I've been reading about the functions of Threads and Process. One major difference between a process and a thread is that a thread shares the resources with the process from which it has been created whereas a process will have its own set of resources. I wanted to test this, so I opened up my Task Manager and opened MS Word and in the task manager, there was a new process called WINWORD.EXE loaded and I again opened another MS Word(Keeping the previous one opened) yet the Task Manager shows only one WINWORD.EXE process running. I just don't get it, since two MS Words are needed to be considered as two separate process(as they don't share resources).

Comment: `winword.exe` is an unlucky choice of test application. Use `calc.exe` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There only is one process in that case. It's just that Word is implemented in such a way that it prevents you creating multiple processes. When you try to start another one, the new process forwards the request to the existing process, and the window is shown by the existing process.

But yes, separate processes do indeed have distinct and isolated address spaces. Try your experiment with a simple program, for instance Notepad.

Comment: However, that doesn't mean that two processes can't share regions of memory between them. Some resources are shared automatically - for example, two projects referencing one library will often share some of the memory of the library.

Comment: @Luaan Copy of write is an optimisation. Conceptually the address spaces are isolated and the virtual memory system may optimise with COW for perf reasons.